# How to search Graylog with a partial Text match

Tags: graylog

The wildcards seem to only apply to non-string literals and text.
I want to match the text on a partial match.

Example:

```
source: org.*.application-* AND "*.pdf"
```

The wildcard works with the source param but not instead of my literal.
How can I use a wildcard inside a string to get back all that match that contains a log with
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.pdf"

Answer (score 3):

Okay - it turns out you remove the quotes - Anytime you add quotes the whole word must match

so this turns out to be the equivalent of what I was asking for:

```
source: org.*.application-* AND *.pdf
```